# jquery crossdomain error callback function was not called codeigniter redirects my request

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

jquery crossdomain error callback function was not called with codeigniter. here is my code

```
$.ajax({type:"GET",
    url:url,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function(data){
        callback(data,extra_data)
    },
    error:function(){
        pq.network_error('Connection Lost!!!')
    }
})
```

here is my codeigniter controller code.

```
function login(){
$result=$this->user->login($this->input->get('user'),$this->input->get('pass'));
if($result){
die($this->__callback(json_encode(array('code'=>TRUE,'token'=>$user_token,'email'=>$result['ProfileDetails']['email']))));
else
    {
        die($this->__callback(json_encode(array('code'=>'Invalid Username or Password!!!..'))));
    }

function __callback($obj){  
return  $this->input->get('callback')."(".$obj.")";
```

}

when i run this code on my host the jquery

```
$this->input->get('user') ,$this->input->get('pass') , $this->input->get('callback')
```

was empty so jquery throws error saying the callback function was not called but when inspect the network in chrome i found out that the codeigniter redirect my request so all my get data was lost here is a sample

http://peequest.com/mobile/login?callback=jQuery1102021599671430885792_1409841367038&user=08130610626&pass=olatunji16&_=1409841367039

redirected url is this

http://www.peequest.com/index.php?/mobile/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know how it happen and i cant even explain it but what i did to solve the problem was to add my controller inside the codeigniter route.php file as the default controller after doing that still dosnt work so i prepend WWW to my url and it was working fyn what i meant is

my new url is this

http://www.peequest.com/mobile/get_feed_comm/41?callback=jQuery110207901261900551617_1409898432426&_=1409898432428

instead of this that i was using before :

http://peequest.com/mobile/login?callback=jQuery1102021599671430885792_1409841367038&user=08130610626&pass=olatunji16&_=1409841367039

the  only diffrence is  WWW